# Non editable row in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am creating a web page using C# ASP.NET and Visual Studio 2008. I would like to create a dataentry form on my web page using `GridView`. Whenever a user may, he/she can edit the record on `GridView` (I have did this using edit, update, cancel option) but I would like to place another button in `GridView` named "Close" by which user can make that particular record "Non-editable". After clicking on close button on `Gridview` that record get locked and no body can edit that record in future.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can do that by adding a column to your table in your database. If the close button was clicked in your gridview, update the data in the database and make it closed so that it cannot be edit in your gridview.

Hope this gives you idea.